# Rewrite fix when running sites side by side?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running two sites side by side. I'm using rewrite conditions to give people access to an old WordPress site that we are phasing out section by section.

I have the following rewrite condition in place which allows people to visit a section called "formulation" in my WordPress site at example.com/formulation

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/formulation) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

The new sections of the site are also at the root level, events, news etc.

When trying to access example.com/events/category/formulation however I keep being taken to example.com/formulation on my old WordPress site, but I need to drill into the events section.

How do I fix this while keeping both /events and /formulation sections browsable?

Comment: Can you explain how the site's are structured? How are the url's and directories relative to each other? Are there other rewrite rules

Comment: Hi - updated with more information